# Authenticate function return none value so user cant login

Tags: django

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from reg.models import Reg_page
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.template import RequestContext
def user_login(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    print("username", username)
    print("password", password)
    user=auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    #user=User.objects.filter(username=username, password=password).exists()
    print("value",user)
    if user:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect("/welcome")
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html", {'error': 'username and password incorrect'})
else:
    return render(request, "login.html")
```

user cannot login because autheticate function return none value it is not give any error 
so let me know how  can I do this?

Comment: You realize that the passwords are hashed? So the fact that the `.exists()` query returns `True` does not mean the password is correct.

Comment: Which means that you have created the user wrong; you presumably didn't use `create_user` or `set_password`, but instead saved the raw password.

Answer (score 0):

A password is *not* stored as raw text in the database, that would be very unsafe. If for example your database is somehow hacked, then the hacker has access to all passwords.

A common protection mechanism is [*hashing* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) where a one-direction hashing function is used to create a "digest" and store this in the database. One authenticates to run the same hashing on the password, and see if the digests are the same. As a result, without knowing the password, the server can know if the two passwords are equal (or well are extremely likely to be equal).

If you make a raw `User` object, you did not pass the password through the hashing function. Authenticating with the digest in the database is not the same as authenticating with the original password, so that indeed fails. The fact that a `User` object exists with that specific raw digest, does not mean that this is the password, and hence you can not expect that because the `.exists()` succeed, that the authentication succeeds as well.

In order to set a password, you should use [**`set_password`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password), or change the password with the [**`changepassword`** command [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-changepassword). If you *create* a user, you should use [**`create_user`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) to hash the entered password accordingly.